# Is an exhaust mute bad for 2 stroke engines?

Tags: engine, exhaust, two-stroke

Will an exhaust baffle have any bad effects on a 2 stroke engine if it's used all of the time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  What is an exhaust mute?  Do you mean an exhaust baffle or muffler?  Can you go look at your question and add a little more information and clarify what you mean by 'mute' and having it 'ON' 24/7?  What are you concerns?  Please add that in too.  Not sure what 'bad' means in the context of your question.  Welcome to the site.  We love questions.  Please ask more.  Cheers!

Comment: @DucatiKiller an exhaust 'mute' is called different things depending on your region, some places call them a 'silencer' and others call them a 'mute'. I don't think I've heard anyone call it a mute in Australia though. Effectively as you said, it's a baffle that slips into the end of a cannon-style muffler.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the exhaust system. If it is a road bike with an exhaust system designed for the road, you need to keep the silencer/muffler/mute on it for optimum performance. Only a full race system, designed to run without a silencer (pretty rare these days with all the noise restrictions even on races) might suffer by having a silencer attached, but that would all depend on the overall design.

Taking the silencer off will affect performance, usually for the worse, as the exhaust will have been made to allow for the resistance to gas flow that the silencer gives. More noise does not necessarily mean better performance.